# How do I delay the loading of a Boostrap modal until the remote content is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, synchronization, bootstrap-modal

I am loading content remotely like this:

```
$('a[rel=modal]').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var modal = $('#modal').modal();
    modal
        .find('.modal-body')
        .load($(this).attr('href'), function (responseText, textStatus) {
            if ( textStatus === 'success' || 
                 textStatus === 'notmodified') 
            {
                modal.show();
            }
    });
});
```

The problem is that the modal shows and 1-2 seconds later the content shows inside and expands the modal, so it's kind of "jumpy". Is there a way to delay the loading of the modal until after the content has been received?

Comment: The modal is being called when you use `$('#modal').modal();` which is why you see it before the content is being loaded. I'm not sure why you are using `.show()`, it isn't used for animation and doesn't seem to be relevant at all http://api.jquery.com/show/. Instead of using `.load()` use an ajax request and on success call and populate the modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your modal is being displayed by `$('#modal').modal();` before you make the request. You should instead show the modal in the callback function for `.load()`, which fires after the request is complete. Here is how you can make it work with minimal changes to your code:

```
$('a[rel=modal]').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var modal = $('#modal');
    modal
        .find('.modal-body')
        .load($(this).attr('href'), function (responseText, textStatus) {
            if ( textStatus === 'success' || 
                 textStatus === 'notmodified') 
            {
                modal.modal("show");
            }
    });
});
```

Notice I remove the `.modal()` call from the jquery object and then I use `modal.modal("show")` which is probably what you were trying to do (instead of `.show()`)

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you very much! After reading the comment I started to try and find a way to rewrite everything but this fixes all my problems Thank you! :)